# Android Studio Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried importing Anthony's Lightning Browsers source code into Android Studio.
https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser

I did:

> git submodule update --init --recursive

..as instructed too.

However, I'm getting this error

> Gradle 'Lightning-Browser-dev' project refresh failed
>
> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Please refer to the source code on Github, I don't know what code to give here to make my problem easier to understand.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have successfully run `git submodule update --init --recursive`?

If this command executes successfully then the `external` folder inside `Lightning-Browser`project should not be empty. I got the same error message `Configuration with name 'default' not found.` before running the above command and my `external` folder was empty. After running it (it takes some time since it downloads stuff) the `external` folder had the `netcipher` project required.

So I suggest make a new clone of the github project:

`git clone https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser.git`

and then issue the git submodule command:

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

and check if the external folder is populated like in the pic below

[image]

Comment: Did it build and run for you?

Comment: I did git submodule update --init --recursive, and the external folder IS populated like that..

Comment: It still not works with the same error or with another one? I did not run it (install the app in an android device or emulator) but gradle sync finished successfully for me.

Comment: Damn, it's working now somehow. This time I did added the clone using Version Control, and then did "git submodule update --init --recursive". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, happy coding!